# Delphi global variable setter

Tags: delphi, variables, global

I got problem with setting global variable in Delphi unit:

```
unit SomeUnit;
...
interface
...
var
variable1: String;
...
implementation

procedure TSomeForm.SetNewVersion(variable1: String);
begin

    variable1 := variable1; //here is problem

end;
```

How to assign value to global variable if it have same name like local argument value from procedure? If that is some form value, that can be done like this:

```
TSomeForm.variable1 = variable1;
```

But problem is when variable is global variable in unit?

```
SomeUnit.variable1 = variable1; // this dont work
```

Comment: You don't have a problem with setting a global variable. More likely you have a problem that you are using a global variable.

Comment: Don't name local variables the same as global variables.  Change your local variable name to something else.  Simple as that.

Comment: `TSomeForm.variable1 = variable1; // this dont work` - it surely does not. Use `:=` for assigning variables, not instead of comparison sign

Comment: = is mistake, i thought :=

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FWIW: The following works as one might expect:

```
var
  SomeForm: TSomeForm;
  variable1: string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TSomeForm }

procedure TSomeForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Assert(SomeUnit.variable1 = '');
  SetNewVersion('1');
  Assert(SomeUnit.variable1 = '1');
end;

procedure TSomeForm.SetNewVersion(variable1: string);
begin
  SomeUnit.variable1 := variable1;
end;
```

To avoid such problems you might consider prefixing arguments with 'A' which is kind of semi-standard in Delphi. And while you're at it, make string parameters `const`:

```
procedure TSomeForm.SetNewVersion(const AVariable1: string);
begin
  variable1 := AVariable1;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can solve your problem by either:

- Choosing a different name for the parameter (or indeed the global variable). Personally I tend to use the name `Value` for the parameter of a setter method. Or,
- Fully qualifying the name like this `SomeUnit.variable1`.

Note that the assignment operator is `:=` and not `=`.

I would strongly recommend that you reconsider the design.

Should the variable really be global? If it is associated with a form instance as is implied by your setter, shouldn't it be a private member variable of the form class.

If the variable really is shared between instances, make the variable a private class variable and the setter a class method.

If your Delphi does not have class variables then move the global variable into the implementation section. As your code stands, there's no point in having a setter because you also expose the backing variable in the interface section.